# How to achieve this using HighCharts Network chart

Tags: charts, highcharts

We are trying to use the network chart in HighCharts to show two sets of nodes connected to a central node, as though they were two separate groups. How can we achieve this? We have tried the API but it didn't get us too far

Any guidance is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the API, there is no such setting as you show.
You can try setting fixed node positions:

```
events: {
  render: function() {
    var chart = this;

    // Pick particular node from nodes array:
    var node = chart.series[0].nodes[0],
      fixedX = chart.plotWidth / 2,
      fixedY = 155;

    node.fixedPosition = {
      x: fixedX,
      y: fixedY
    };

    node.plotX = fixedX;
    node.plotY = fixedY;
  }
}
```

Live demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sqbu3v2y/

Blog article on how to customize network graph.

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/network-graph